# SSL connection , error

Tags: ssl, blackberry

I am trying to connect through SSL from my phone device to my server.

When i am debugging the application on the device while i try to connect to my server i get this in the logs :

```
> Opening URL:
> https://193.158.3.165:8443/low-level-sample/subscribe?username=fk&password=ckd&appid=35[0.0]
> 82-M4687r9k9k836r980kO2395i32i66y10a34&address=320ef999&osversion=5.0.0.669&model=9520&type=public&f[0.0]
> ield1=844;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public
>     SSL:->CH
```

and an error on the device that i cant reach my server. The server is accessible by the browser of the device though.

Any ideas what this mean :

> SSL:->CH

Looking at it again i suppose this is something like the first step of the handshake between the client and the server?

Comment: well is the sample server from the blackberry forum so i guess is correct. Thats what they are saying to use.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize this was for a BB push notification app (I checked your recent questions).  Are you getting this error, when a client app on your device is attempting to register for push notifications?

Comment: Yes! Have you ever used it before?? I am getting this error when the sample client app tries to connect to the server sample app which tries to connect to the RIM server for the token. you could see in more detail my problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947917/push-notifications-through-bes-bis-blackberry and here http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Push-Notifications-through-BES-BIS/td-p/2300969   thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: Ok, what part of that URL are you actually putting into your code?  Is some of that long URL autogenerated?  Can you tell me what URL you have hardcoded?  And, are you using some kind of custom `Connection` code that automatically appends to the URL?

Comment: also, is this really just the same problem as the previous question (that you linked to)?  If so, I would recommend closing this question.  If you have more to add to the previous question, you can take the information here, and **edit** the previous question to add it.

Comment: Well is not the same question. The other question was about the BlackBerry error. In this question i was trying to figure out what that SSL response actually means.  The code is given from RIM so i didnt change anything. Through the application though , i give some info provided to me my RIM as my push port number , my app-id the BPS server URL and my local server URL.

Comment: Which code?  Are you using the PushAgent.java?  It's important to explain how you're generating this error.  If you only want to know what the `SSL:->CH` log output means, **yes**, it shows that the first step of the SSL handshaking process is attempted, and then nothing else happens, because of the network connectivity problem.

Comment: I am using these server/client samples (low level initiator / Push Demo) https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/using_sample_push_initiators.html#jza135750885609 What is the code you are refering to? I am running the server as suggested , put the app in my phone , use the correct settings from RIM and the error i explained is following. Theres not really anything i personally do. Is just the code given. I just put RIMs settings in the app , nothing more

Comment: Don't worry about what code I'm referring to.  We need to know what code you're referring to.  What source code are you using to generate a connection using this connection string?  Please don't point to the documentation on the Push Service.  Post the java code you're using into the question here.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: Ok i found out where the problem lies. Before registering to the BIS server for push , the application tries to register with my local server(server sample). The thing is that in this line of code : conn = Connector.open( httpUrl );  i was getting a socketBase ioexception with error code 127 that was terminating the app. If i catch the exception and do nothing about it i am able to continue with registering with the BIS server and push works. Any ideas why this exception though?

Comment: I have no idea, unless you post the code, along with any relevant data (for example, the value of `httpUrl`).